# 99% humidity during the night and indoors using DHT22

Tags: dht22

I've been playing with the DHT22, but the humidity values are very intriguing.

During the night or indoors the sensor is returning 99%.
While the temperature values looks good.

Here is a visualization for the last 12 hours:
[image]

Before 10:30 the sensor was indoor, I put it out to test if I still have the same values. The sensor is fully exposed to the sun after 10:30.

I'm using the Adafruit DHT python library to fetch the values:

```
import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import time


def get_data(sensor, pin):
    h, t = dht.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    return h, t


def main_loop():
    while True:
        h,t = get_data(dht.DHT22, 4)
        payload = {
            'temperature': round(t, 2),
            'humidity': round(h, 1),
            'timestamp': int(time.time() * 1000)}
        print payload
        time.sleep(60)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_loop()
```

As you can see, the sensor is plugged in the GPIO#4 of the RPi3.

I don't know if this is a problem, if the sensor is broken, but 99% humidity is very excessive.

Since I don't have anything else to verify these values, how can I understand the problem and fix it ?

Comment: *"the temperature values looks good"* -> Are you sure? It jumps 10 degrees in as many minutes at about the same time as the humidy seems to be correcting (10:30-40).  There are also some excessive inverse value changes in this table generally, I think.  You should really explain **how** you are taking the measurements if you expect anyone to make an informed guess about the issue.

Comment: Indoors, are you in a grow environment, where you're turning off large grow lamps at ~1500 hrs? Humidity rises sharply after lights go off (although to 99% seems a bit excessive, unless you are turning off any extraction fans at the same time as lights-out).

Comment: @goldilocks : before 10:30 the sensor was in my room, I wanted to try it outside this is why the temperature jumped suddenly. Outside the sensor is fully exposed to the sun.

Comment: @stevieb: No, I'm not in a grow environment, in the middle of the city.

Comment: A good test to ensure things are working correctly is to have another hygrometer to put alongside your sensor. That's how I ensure my DHT11 is returning me correct results for my grow environment control system.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @goldilocks: I want to understand if it's a problem or not, I don't know what other informations can be relevant to you ? I'm just using the simplest use case.

Comment: @joan I'm trying to understand the problem.

Comment: You shoud not expose a DHT22 directly to the sun. For more, please read: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236530/humidity-sensor-dht21-am2301-not-measuring-humidity-in-a-lamobo-r1-banana-pi-r/236751

Comment: Try different software, e.g. my http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD

Comment: @joan same results, it's returning 99.9%

Comment: where do you live?

Comment: Connect the sensor to a +3V pin, instead of a +5V pin (that was my main problem in the link above)